# Vk_Api как узнать информацию из пересланного/ответа

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, requests, long-poll

Я использую UserLongPoll. Пишу страничного бота.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, не могу взять информацию из ответа/пересланного сообщения
Пример:

```
if response == prefix + " +др":
    id = 1
    vk.friends.add(
        user_id = id
    )
```

Айди я хочу получать из ответа на сообщение. То есть вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Берется айди из ответа, добавляет его в друзья. Все просто. Не могу продолжить писать бота, по скольку на этом дальше все основывается.
На сколько я знаю, в BotLongPoll это можно сделать так:

```
event.obj.reply_message['from_id']
```

А в UserLongPoll не знаю.

```
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='токен пользователя')
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
prefix = "префикс команд который будет использовать пользователь"
dovs = []

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.text:
        response = event.text
        if response == prefix + " команда":
        # выполнить там что то, к примеру в друзья добавить.
```